# Как создать список содержащий только числа кончающиеся на 9 из другого спискa?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить задачу для егэ, где нужно импортировать набор чисел и найти все оканчивающиеся на 9. Понимаю что с 3 строкой что-то не так но что именно хз

```
with open('17-354.txt') as f:
    s = [int(x) for x in f]
    s9 = [int(x) for x in s if x % 2 == 9]
    print(s9)
```

Comment: `x % 10 == 9`..

Comment: Либо наоборот в первом списковом сокращении  поставить `if x[-1] == '9'`, пока это ещё строки. Но лучше, конечно, проверять уже числа, а то вдруг там пробелы лишние или ещё что. `int(x)` во втором сокращении уже лишнее, кстати, там уже числа.

Comment: ``x % 2 == 9`` остаток от деления на два никогда не равен 9.

Answer (score 2):

Наугад нашёл, что нужно выполнить

```
s9 = [int(x) for x in s if abs(x) % 10 == 9]
```

Comment: Кстати, да, остаток от отрицательных чисел в Питоне - тот ещё сюрприз. А `int()` всё-таки лишний тут уже.

Comment: жалко, что наугад...

Answer (score 0):

```
s9 = [int(x) for x in s if x[-1] == 9]
```

Можно ещё так попробовать

Comment: можно попробовать - попробуйте. Увидите, что в коде автора вопроса это не сработает.

Comment: `x` тут число, из него не получится срез взять